# Animating single instance of a class at a time

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I'm using CSS to flip images when a user clicks. It works great across all browsers, but issues arise when there are multiple instances on the same page. They all animate simultaneously.

How can I target a specific instance at a time?

http://jsfiddle.net/2ega7yLt/307/

```
$('.card').click(function(){
    $('.card').toggleClass('applyflip');    
}.bind(this));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this)` for the reference of the currently clicked element.

```
$('.card').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('applyflip');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ega7yLt/307/)

Answer (score 4):

Within the click handler use `this` to reference the element that raised the event:

```
$('.card').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('applyflip');
});
```